# Can't figure out how to append mySQL table with input form content(HTML) using native python

Tags: python, mysql, forms, sockets, server

I have a registration form on a website and need to build a server on python which will receive this forms data and send to a database as a text. I have found information about it only through Flask. My question is can I do it with a native python and how can I do it.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that with native Python (unless you want to build your own web framework and database connector).

The most common web frameworks are Django and Flask. Pick one of them and start studying...